# How to fix @font-face glitches in Firefox 3.5

Tags: html, css, fonts, font-face, firefox3.5

In existing code I had CSS @font-face declarations for .EOT embedded fonts that worked flawlessly actually, in internet explorer.  So now I read that Firefox does embedded now too, in 3.5, except it embeds .ttf fonts directly. So I altered the @font-face declaration for firefox and gave it a shot:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: FontX;
  src: url("FontX.eot");   //previous decl.
  src: local("FontX"), url("FontX.ttf") format("truetype");
}
```

It works - but hardly flawlessly.

First, the italic and bold don't show up on the page, though they did previously with the .EOT font.

Secondly and more disturbing is the following behavior:

Firefox flashes the default font for a half second before displaying the embedded ttf font!

This looks really really dumb.

As far as this second problem, the reason I'm hoping there might be a work around is that with [Cufon](http://wiki.github.com/sorccu/cufon/usage) embedded fonts, there is the exact same problem. However, they provide the Cufon.now() JS function you call right before the closing `</body>` tag and that solves the problem for them.  SHould probably have already taken a look at the JS code for that function but am hardly an expert at any of this.

Also that same default font flashing is not present in IE or Safari.

Comment: Not sure if this will help you, but you may find Paul Irish's bullet-proof `@font-face` implementation useful: http://paulirish.com/2009/bulletproof-font-face-implementation-syntax/

Comment: The flash of unstyled content is a firefox-specific issue. Their implementation shows the content while the font is downloading (so it should stop happening once the font is in the user's cache). There isn't a lot you can do about it right now. Safari waits until the font has downloaded before showing it. I can see the reasoning behind both ways of doing it - especially seeing as some fonts can weigh in at over a megabyte and not everyone is on broadband.

Comment: As for the italics thing, IIRC Firefox requires an italic version of the font. It won't fake it if there isn't one.

Comment: Olly, how would I do that specifcally,  the font I'm using doesn't have seperate ttf files for italic  and bold (acutally the norm seems to be just one file for all three).  WHat specifically would I need to do as far as @font-face declarations to get Firefox to display italic and bold embedded (I think I've tried some variations already.)

If in the body style, you just say body { FONT-FAMILY: "FontX"; FONT-SIZE: 140%;} for example, and FontX is on the user's system, Firefox does display italic and bold.

Comment: Olly, I see now you're implying if there's just one font file, then that means there is no italic or bold info in that  file and the browser has to fake it, which FireFox won't do - is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

If you are only using non-standard fonts in headers and small amounts of text, I'd recommend using [sIFR](http://www.mikeindustries.com/blog/sifr/). This little JavaScript/Flash library works by replacing select elements with a small light-weight flash object, which displays your fonts the same across all browsers... You can even select the fonts sIFR generates, just as you would any other text on your webpage.

Take a look at the [example page](http://www.mikeindustries.com/blog/files/sifr/2.0/).

Comment: For small pieces of text, I can verify that Cufon fonts work much better.  Well actually, their interface isn't anywhere near as convoluted as siFR, and for small pieces of text they work great with zero delay (if you use their now() command).  I have read there is significan delay with siFR (and also its flash - Cufon isn't flash.)  For large pieces of multiline text I ran into some problems with Cufon which are probably solvable, as they provide a lot of documentation.

Comment: Aye. Cufon seems easier to use. I'd personally choose sIFR over Cufon because of the option to select text in sIFR. And combining sIFR with jQuery makes selecting stuff to sIFR-enable easier. Personal taste, I guess :)

Answer (score -2):

For italic, you need to add

```
@font-face {
  font-family: ...;
  src: url(...);
  font-style: italic;
}
```

Comment: THat didn't cause Firefox to display the Italic.  I just tried it.